# How can I make a method to return an object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I need the `getData` method to return `this.name` and `this.assignatures` as an object.

```js
class Student {
  constructor(name, assignatures) {
    this.name = name;
    this.assignatures = assignatures = [ "Javascript", "HTML", "CSS" ];
  }

  getData() {
    return [ this.name, this.assignatures ]
  }
}

let newStudent = new Student("Tucu")

console.log(newStudent)

let dataNewStudent = newStudent.getData();

console.log(dataNewStudent)
```

Comment: Have you tried using an [object initializer](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)?

Comment: Use {} instead of []. [] is an array

Comment: Why not just `return this`? It's already an object.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> return [ this.name, this.assignatures ]

to

> return {name:this.name, assignatures:this.assignatures}

```js
    class Student {
      constructor(name, assignatures) {
        this.name = name;
        this.assignatures = assignatures = [ "Javascript", "HTML", "CSS" ];
      }
    
      getData() {
        return {name:this.name, assignatures:this.assignatures}
      }
    }
    
    let newStudent = new Student("Tucu")
    
    console.log(newStudent)
    
    let dataNewStudent = newStudent.getData();
    
    console.log(dataNewStudent)
```

Comment: Make your code a stack snippet so we can click the Run button to see the output.